# Pandas Dataframe, join two dt when columns are not equal

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Assume I have two datatables, identical shape, say N rows and 2 columns. They have same columns names "One", "Two"

Call first table "left", then call second table "right".

How can I return a new datatable **FROM** table "Left", when value from two tables in column "One" are **not equal**?

EX:

```
Table "Left"
One    Two
1       2
1       2
2       3
2       5
3       6


Table "Right"
One    Two
1       2
2       2
2       3
5       5
3       8


Output Table 
One    Two
1       2
2       5
```

Thank you!

Comment: @Psidom When column "One" is not equal, return all values ONLY from left

Comment: Just figured out your logic. You can check the answer. Basically construct the boolean series with the condition and subset the left data frame.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think you need this:

```
left[left.One.values != right.One.values]

# One   Two
#1  1     2
#3  2     5
```

Comment: Had tried this, raised error "ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects"

Comment: You might have different index from `left` and `right`, if you don't care about the index, you can compare the numpy array of Column *one* with *values*.

Comment: I see. Index might be the issue. But with values at least I got an output, just need to verify if it is what I want. Thank you so much!