# Pandas join on table1.x != table2.x

Tags: python, pandas

I came across this SQL problem and wonder if I could solve it in python pandas.

**The SQL problem:**
Table point holds the x coordinate of some points on x-axis in a plane, which are all integers.

Write a query to find the shortest distance between two points in these points.

```
| x   |
|-----|
| -1  |
| 0   |
| 2   |
```

**I have initiate the pandas dataframe as below.**

```
import pandas as pd
point = pd.DataFrame(np.array([-1,0,2]), columns=['x'])
```

I was trying to do like

```
p1 = point
p2 = point.copy()
p1.merge(p2, on='x', condition = ('!='))
```

But I know there is no such conditions.

Can anyone provide a solution to this problem in pandas?

Note: My problem is different from [join two dt when columns are not equal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42966516/pandas-dataframe-join-two-dt-when-columns-are-not-equal), so it is not a duplicate. My problem is about appending all values to each of the values in the original set. The problem in the link is about finding out the difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```py
point = [-1, 0, 1]
ix = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([point, point], names=['a', 'b'])
df = pd.DataFrame(index=ix).reset_index()
df = df[df.a != df.b]
```

will [(rather) efficiently get you a dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46744050/51685) with the unique combinations of two coordinates, like an outer join would in SQL:

```
   a  b
1 -1  0
2 -1  1
3  0 -1
5  0  1
6  1 -1
7  1  0
```

After that, you can get the distance with

```
>>> (df.a - df.b).abs().min()
1
```

Answer (score 1):

This is filter after cross join

```
p1.assign(key=1).merge(p2.assign(key=1),on='key').loc[lambda x : x['x_x']!=x['x_y']]
Out[29]: 
   x_x  key  x_y
1   -1    1    0
2   -1    1    2
3    0    1   -1
5    0    1    2
6    2    1   -1
7    2    1    0
```