# Join where keys are not equal in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like this:

```
data = {'teamid': [1, 2, 3, 4], 'gameid': [1, 1, 2, 2], 'rebounds': [20, 35, 43, 15]}
game_df = pd.DataFrame(data=data)
print(game_df)

   teamid  gameid  rebounds
0       1       1        20
1       2       1        35
2       3       2        43
3       4       2        15
```

I would like to join it to it self to produce a dataframe like this:

```
wanted_data = {'teamid': [1, 2, 3, 4], 'gameid': [1, 1, 2, 2], 'rebounds': [20, 35, 43, 15],
               'teamid_opponent': [2, 1, 4, 3], 'rebound_opponent': [35, 20, 15, 43]}
wanted_df = pd.DataFrame(data=wanted_data)
print(wanted_df)

   teamid  gameid  rebounds  teamid_opponent  rebound_opponent
0       1       1        20                2                35
1       2       1        35                1                20
2       3       2        43                4                15
3       4       2        15                3                43
```

In SQL I would just do something like this:

```
SELECT * from game_df df1 join game_df df2 on df1.gameid = df2.gameid and df1.teamid != df2.teamid
```

But i haven't been able to find anything in the pandas docs or on here for a way to replicate this in pandas itself. I looked on here and found this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42966516/pandas-dataframe-join-two-dt-when-columns-are-not-equal) but it isn't quite the same as what I'm trying to do. I've only found examples of trying to join where keys are equal.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is one way use `merge`

```
Yourdf=game_df.merge(game_df,on='gameid',suffixes =['','_opponent']).query('teamid!=teamid_opponent')
Out[42]: 
   teamid  gameid  rebounds  teamid_opponent  rebounds_opponent
1       1       1        20                2                 35
2       2       1        35                1                 20
5       3       2        43                4                 15
6       4       2        15                3                 43
```

Answer (score 1):

I will also add seeing the answer made me think of a different way to do this as well so I will post that for posterity

```
Yourdf=game_df.merge(game_df,on='gameid',suffixes =['','_opponent'])
Yourdf[Yourdf.teamid != Yourdf.teamid_opponent]

   teamid  gameid  rebounds  teamid_opponent  rebounds_opponent
1       1       1        20                2                 35
2       2       1        35                1                 20
5       3       2        43                4                 15
6       4       2        15                3                 43
```